# Reading CSV file with semi-colon-separated values in cells

Tags: javascript, csv, sheetjs

I have a comma-separated .csv file in which some "cells" contain semi-colon separated values. Example:

```
A,B
1,a;b;c
2,d;e;f
```

The following isn't working as expected with SheetJS:

```
var workbook = XLSX.read(e.target.result, {type:'array', FS: ','})
var data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets['Sheet1'], {raw: true, defval: ""})
```

It seems to consider the semi-colons also as separators, and new columns are created. The expected output should be `{'A': [1, 2], 'B': ['a;b;c', 'd;e;f']}`.

**UPDATE**

I noticed it does work as intended if I add quotes to the semi-colon-separated values, i.e.:

```
A,B
1,"a;b;c"
2,"d;e;f"
```

Wondering if it's possible to make it work without the quotes. MS Excel displays it properly without the quotes.

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

In a nutshell, here's how I read the file:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
reader.onloadend = function (e) {
    if (e.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {
        var workbook = XLSX.read(e.target.result, {type:'array', FS: ','});
        var data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets['Sheet1'], {raw: true, defval: ""});
        ...
    }
}
```